# Enumerate - Python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enumerate

I have two lists with just one element as follows(each of these two lists always contains only one element):

```
Vnew = [600]
Newoints2 = [(2447,3480)]
```

I'm trying to bring both of them together using the following code sample:

```
for i, key in enumerate(Vnew2):
  pos3[key] = newpoints2[i]
```

But this returns an error as `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

I actually did this one for other lists which have more than one element. It worked fine and got the output as `{0:(1245,674),1:(2457,895),...}`

Can someone find the mistake here?

Comment: Seems like `pos3` is a list when it should be a dict.

Comment: Post what `pos3` is

Comment: @Farhan, Thanks for pointing me out the mistake. I fixed that with `pos3={}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to concatenate the lists into a new list. You don't always need to enumerate through the list.

You will be able to do this by `Vnew + Newoints2`